# How can one connect to VPN from public wifi, connection process?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, firewall

First of all I would like to apologize if my english is not perfect, this is because I'm not a native english.

So, to speak about the problem I'm facing : 
I'm going in a few days in a foreign country, where internet is widely controlled and filtered, and this is quite boring since, websites like google are filtered.

So I searched, how to bypass this problem, and the most common answer was to use a VPN, I've made some researches to understand how VPN works and as far as I understand, it works like the following :
When you are connected to a network, you can create a virtual tunnel to a distant server/host, and then you send all of your requests to this host instead of using the network that will (or will not if filtered) send your request to the internet. So it would be pretty like if you where connected to your host's network.

In order to try to understand a bit more, how this VPN system works, I wanted to make some experiment with a nearby public wifi that requires my email address to let me do stuff on internet (this acts like the foreign network that filters my requests). Several topics about VPN say that with a VPN working well, I will not need to give my email address to go on the internet.

So I tried, several ways to connect to my distant host with no success.

First of all, I rode that those public wifi block the DNS resolution until we give what they are asking for, in this case an email address. 
So I thought if I already have the ip address of my host, there will be no need to get that ISP's DNS resolution. So I tried to ping my host directly (this is not the real address of course):

```
$ ping 256.256.256.256
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

and sometimes I get the additionnal :

```
$ ping 256.256.256.256
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

That show, that having the ip address is not enough to reach the internet. 
So I tried to connect to my host using ssh, the result was not successfull either:

```
$ ssh user@256.256.256.256
ssh: connect to host 256.256.256.256 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

So it seems I can't connect to my server this way either.

So the question is how VPN can bypass wifi firewall or stuff like this, because every outbound traffic is filtered until I give my email address. It is like I have a virtual tunnel ready, but the entry is locked.
It would be great for me understand clearly how this process works because it is really unclear in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a vpn client to work you must first have an internet connection ... even one which blocks a known list of remote IP addresses

vpn works because once installed your vpn client is just yet another connection just like any other network connection from your local laptop/mobile  ... and so it cannot be distinguished from being just some connection from your client to any remote web page because that is exactly what a vpn connection is

easiest way to convince yourself of how simple it can be is to rent out a remote machine ( ubuntu / debian ) from say ovh.com or https://www.hetzner.com and install a vpn server on that remote machine and then install its corresponding vpn client  ( linux/osx/windows/android/ios ) on your laptop or mobile phone ... this is suprisingly easy using below github repo

from my experience an easy one which is free and open source is  https://git.io/vpnclients  ( you MUST install your own vpn server see instructions in the repo ) ... it is far easier, with some basic linux skill, to install your own vpn server on your own remote machine than to use a paid vpn service ... needless to say also more private ... be aware that ability to access a vpn client web page is itself often blocked while in an abusive totalitarian government country so plan accordingly

and yes this one works while in those abusive totalitarian government countries

after logging onto your own remote ubuntu vps box issue following to install your own vpn server

```
wget https://git.io/vpnsetup -O vpnsetup.sh && sudo sh vpnsetup.sh
```

above will finish by showing you settings which you must remember so you can connect using the vpn client

> without a vpn client while in a restrictive country

me <-> desired web page  // blocked due to abusive government

> now using a vpn client

me <-> my remote vpn server IP address <-> desired web page   // this works

Why ? because that remote vpn server address is not recognized by that abusive gov and so traffic from  ( me <-> my remote vpn server ) flows OK

Comment: I see but the thing that is unclear in my mind is, when my laptop has the vpn client but has no internet access, it is not connected to anything, but when I connect my laptop to a public wifi which block my requests, how can it let my vpn client reach my ovh server because the wifi blocks my outgoing requests ?

Comment: By the way I forgot to thank you for taking the time to answer, so : Thank you :)

Comment: @CYRUS: The short answer is "it cannot".

Comment: @grawity I see, so even with a VPN there is no way to bypass a restricted wifi then ?

Comment: @Scott Stensland: Thank you for the edit, so my problem for the foreign country is solved this is a big thing done, but now, my question is why does this doesn't work for the public wifi ? could it be because the ISP of that public wifi is just blocking every outbound request until I give my email address ?

Comment: @CYRUS bring with you some extra email accounts which will work in that country (gmail is blocked in some so avoid gmail)  and use those

Comment: @Scott Stensland: yeah for the foreign country things are resolved :), but to close the thread do you confirm that, if a public wifi needs an email to provide internet access, there is no "easy" way to reach the internet without giving this email address ? Even if we have buch of VPN waiting for our requests ?

Comment: my take is that those two challenges are orthogonal ... wifi which prompts for your email just give it your specially created toy non-gmail email address then once connected to wifi then setup vpn client (and vpn server) ... be aware that ability to access a vpn client web page is itself often blocked while in an abusive totalitarian government country so plan accordingly

Comment: @CYRUS: The VPN servers themselves are _part of_ the Internet. If you have no Internet access at all, then you cannot reach the VPN servers.